# Google Drive to Instagram File Location?

Tags: internal-storage, ram

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 7.0 that had about 29GB of 32GB memory full. I then tried to post a large video file (3+GB) from Google Drive over to my Instagram, but it got stuck on Instagram's "loading" screen for quite a while. I thought maybe the system was hanging, so I backed out and closed all my phone apps. Since then, my phone's file storage went to 100% full, and I can't find that video file anywhere on my system to delete it.

Is there a way to find where that file is to delete it? It's not showing in My Files, it's not showing as a hidden file, and it's not showing under any file management apps that I've tried on Google Play. I know that this is the file that's causing the error, but I can't find it to delete it. If you have any recommendations, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an outright guess, but the first thing to check is to clear the cache of both apps. Go to the **Settings** app, then **Apps**. Select the Instagram app from the list, then **Storage** and **Clear cache**. Do the same for the Google Drive app.